# Wordpress error - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress. I had to move website from one hosting to another hosting service provider.

What I have done is, downloaded the entire wordpress files, with the theme I have used and uploaded to new hosting server.

Exported the DB from phpMyAdmin and and imported in another hosting(sql file), before that I have created DB under MySQL Database, with same username and password.

All went well, now the error i get is "Error establishing a database connection".

Not sure where I went wrong as I have not done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cPanel, check your Database Username and Password, and also the Database Name. Make sure all the:

- Hostname
- Username
- Password
- Database

Are all correct to the new server. I am definitely sure, if you are using a shared hosting, the username will change.

[image]
<sub>(source: [inmotionhosting.com](http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/website/databases/change-db-pw.png))</sub>

Change the details accordingly in `wp-config.php` here:

[image]

Comment: @praven-Under wp-config.php file from which i have downloaded from the previous hosting, i have used same DB_NAME and DB_PASSWORD in the new DB i have created in new hosting. Probably some issue after importing the sql file in phpMyadmin.

Comment: @Sharath-designer Check, the DB_NAME will surely be different.

Comment: @Praveen-No, it is same, as i myself have created to match the name in wp-config.php

Comment: @Sharath-designer Can you show a screenshot of the cPanel page in the new and old site?

Comment: @Praveen-I have uploaded above the new hosting screenshot, the old site i cannot get it now, as i cannot login, but probably not the same, must be a older version.

Comment: @Sharath-designer Can you please click MySQL Databases. And share a screenshot.

Comment: @Sharath-designer Show your Code, the `wp-config.php`? The database part.

Comment: @Praveen-done, please see above